# If Hashtables use separate chaining, why are duplicate keys not possible?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

So I'm a bit confused about this one.
If Hashtables use separate chaining (or linear probing), why won't the following print out both values?

```
         Hashtable<Character, Integer> map = new Hashtable<>();
         map.put('h', 0);
         map.put('h', 1);
         System.out.println(map.remove('h')); // outputs 1
         System.out.println(map.get('h')); // outputs null
```

I'm trying to understand why, given 2 identical keys, the hashtable won't use separate chaining in order to store both values. Did I understand this somewhat incorrectly or has Java just not implemented collision handling in their hashtable class?

Another question that might tie together would be, how does a hashtable using linear probing, given a key, know which value is the one we are looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hash value of the key, gets you to the correct bucket.  Then you apply the appropriate algorithm to find the exact key in that bucket and return the associated value.  If you had two of the same identical key, which value would you return?  If you want to store multiple values for the same key, then you can put them in a list and return the list associated with that key.

Comment: Well if the hash value of the key gets you to the correct bucket, and you use a different algorithm to find another key inside the bucket, I'm assuming that the values would be identical so it doesn't matter? @WJS

Comment: No the bucket holds many different keys and their values.  By getting to the correct bucket you narrow what you have to search for.

Comment: Yes, but given a key, how would you know which value it is you're looking for? Even if you narrow it down, you still have to make a choice..? @WJS

Comment: You're not looking for a particular value.  You're looking for a value associated with the key.  All you have is the key.  Just like with an array, all you have is an index.

Comment: Oh I see, so if you know your hashtable uses chaining, when using get, you will be retrieving the list associated with the key, and use a for loop to iterate through that narrowed down range of values to search for your particular value. @WJS

Comment: Close,  You search for a particular key and return the value associated with it.

Comment: Yep so basically, the key is hashed for getting the correct bucket. Once you have the correct bucket, you don't use the hashed key anymore to search for your value, but you are using your unhashed key inside the bucket to search for it. Right?  @WJS

Comment: Yes.  But the hashed key and the actual key are the same thing.  The hashCode is just a number obtained from the key that is used to find the bucket.  But the original key is still used within the bucket.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand why, given 2 identical keys, the hashtable won't use separate chaining in order to store both values.

The specification for `Map` (i.e. the javadoc) says that **only one** value is stored for each key.  So that's what `HashTable` and `HashMap` implementations do.

Certainly the separate chaining doesn't stop someone from implementing a hash table with that property.  The pseudo-code for `put(key, value)` on a hash table with separate chaining is broadly as follows:

1. Compute the hash value for the key.
2. Compute an index in the array of hash chains from the hash value.  (The computation is `index = hash % array.length` or something similar.)
3. Search the hash chain at the computed index for an entry that matches the key.
4. If you found the entry for the key on the chain, update the value in the entry.
5. If you didn't find the entry, create an entry and add it to the chain.

If you repeat that for the same key, you will compute the same hash value, search the same chain, and find the same entry.  You then update it, and there is still only one entry for that key ... as required by the specification.

In short, the above algorithm has no problem meeting the `Map.put` API requirements.

Comment: But doesn't number 4 invalidate ht idea of chaining? If you find the entry for the key, you don't update the value, you add another value to the bucket found at the index.

Comment: No.  It doesn't invalidate the idea of chaining.  Chaining does NOT mean that you must add a new entry each time.  Chaining just means representing a group of entries as a chain; i.e. as a kind of linked list.  I think you have misunderstood or misinterpreted ... something.

Comment: :P Yes I assume so too. To be honest I was trying to find a way to have characters be keys that map to integer values, and I found that I can't do that because duplicate characters are just overwritten. So my interpretation of what chaining does is probably flawed.

Comment: If you want to map from one character to a group of integers, what you need is a multi-map not a simple map.  But you can implement that as a `Map<Character, Set<Integer>>` or a `Map<Character, List<Integer>>`.  But either way the behavior of a class like `HashMap` or `HashTable` is clearly documented in its javadocs.  You should read those *carefully* ... rather than making unwarranted assumptions base on how you *think* it might be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mis-understanding how hash tables work.  Imagine I am looking for someone with an id of 227828.  Say I have 1000 such people.  I can search all 1000 and eventually find that ID and the person to whom it belongs.

But if their ids are used as keys in a hash table it is easier.  Using the id as the key, say the hash function returns 0 for an even id and 1 for an odd id.  Then all I have to do is find the box that contains even ids.  Ideally I would then only have to search thru 500 entries to find the key - i.e. the id, and return the value associated with it.

But hash functions are more sophisticated and there are many such boxes or buckets.  And the appropriate box or bucket can be identified and then be searched for the proper key.  And then return its associated value.